# Make a div move out of screen (top) on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, header

I'd want to create  an effect like the header of this site : [Tigre Blanc](http://tigreblanc.fr/)
My code goes like this:

```
<div id="header">                                 
        <center><div class="menubutton" onclick="openNav()"><img src="assets/images/openmenu.png" style="width:6%"></div></center>                    
    </div>
```

I have no idea wich functions can make it move out of the screen like this. I guess the kind of js code to make it start but can't figure out the animation to use.

Js:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$(".header").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
});

/*win.scroll(function(){
scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
scrollRatio = 1 - scrollPosition / 300;
$(".header").css("opacity", scrollRatio);
*/

/*$(window).scroll(function(){
var scrollVar = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.header').css("opacity", 1 - scrollVar/300);
})*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkoxvnyv/)?

HTML

```
<div class="a"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.a{
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  background:#000;

;
}

.b{
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {transform: translateY(0%);}
    95%  {transform: translateY(-110%);}
    100% {transform: translateY(-120%);}
}
```

JS

```
$('.a').click(function(){
  $('.a').toggleClass('b');
});
```

You can simply use something like

```
transform: translateY(n);
```

with a transition like

```
transition: all 1.5s ease;
```

for very simple up and down movements, I opted for a keyframe since I noticed that there were subtle bounce effect.

Comment: Yes this was very simple :/ I'm gonna try it later and let you know I have an other div problem to fix right now ;) Thx